# Error: Compile Error: Extra ')',

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforcedx, developer-console

I'm trying to call My apex class in Test calss at that time I got an error. Please anyone help me to resolve.

Test Calss

```
@isTest
private class UnplannedCallsTest{

    @isTest static void caluclateEndDateTime(){

        //Create an US User

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='US Livestock Rep'];

        User u = new User(Alias = 'FAINR', Email='robert.b.fain@zoetis.com',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Fain', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='robert.b.fain@zo.com');

        System.runAs(u) {

            //Create an Account

            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.name = 'Test Account';
            acc.ZTS_US_Business_Class__c = 'Sub-Class 1';
            acc.ZTS_EU_Country__c = 'United States';
            acc.BillingCity = 'Test City';
            acc.ZTS_US_State_Province__c  = 'Ohio';
            acc.BillingStreet = 'Test Street';
            acc.ZTS_US_NARC_ID__c='12345';
            insert acc;


            //Create one Call

            Call__c call = new Call__c();
            call.ZTS_EU_Account__c = acc.Id;
            call.Name = 'Test Call';
            dateTime dt = system.now();
            call.ZTS_EU_Sub_Type__c = 'Account Call';
            call.ZTS_EU_Start_Date_Time__c = dt+3;
            call.ZTS_EU_End_Date_Time__c = dt+4;
            call.ZTS_EU_Status__c = 'Submitted';
            call.ZTS_EU_Duration__c = '0.5 Hour';

            insert call;

            // This line I'm getting error called   Error: Compile Error: Extra ')', at 'call'. at line 43 column 59

            USCallTriggerService.beforeInsert(Call__c call);
        }

    }

}
```

Any syntax error at this line Please help me to resolve.

Thanks,
Sekhar

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this line :

`USCallTriggerService.beforeInsert(Call__c call);`

it should be `USCallTriggerService.beforeInsert(call);`

But not sure why are you calling beforeInsert explicility.